# shiny - function for different tabs get executed on first load

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

Shiny is executing functions used in other tabs at first load. For a minimal example, look at the following app which is adopted from wch [here](https://github.com/rstudio/shinydashboard/issues/25#issuecomment-127398759). There are two menu items on this app. If you click on sidebar menu item A, it should execute a `renderUI` function which will produce a menu item through `output$A_panel`. This app does it perfectly. However, if you look at your R console, you will see both `Inside A Panel` and `Inside B Panel`  are printed. This imply that both `renderUI` function got executed when the app is first loaded and shiny mere hid them unless the user clicks on menu item B.

I have an app that uses similar technique but the executed functions use SQL queries and some computation which I do not want to do on the first load. It critically slows down my app. Is there any way to prevent this auto-execution from happening?

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
      dashboardHeader(),
      dashboardSidebar(
sidebarMenu(id = "sidebarmenu",
            menuItem("A", tabName = "a",  icon = icon("group", lib="font-awesome")),
            menuItem("B", tabName = "b", icon = icon("check-circle", lib = "font-awesome")),
            conditionalPanel("input.sidebarmenu === 'a'",
                             uiOutput('A_panel')
                             ),
            conditionalPanel("input.sidebarmenu === 'b'",
                             uiOutput('B_panel')
                            )
),
sliderInput("x", "Outside of menu", 1, 100, 50)
),
dashboardBody()
)

server <- function(input, output) {

output$A_panel <- renderUI({
       cat('Inside A Panel \n')
       sliderInput("b", "Under A", 1, 100, 50)
})
output$B_panel <- renderUI({
       cat('Inside B Panel \n')
       sliderInput("b", "Under B", 1, 100, 50)
        })

}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ConditionalPanel` controls the visibility of the UI, not the execution.
A quick fix in this case is to get out from the function based on the value of `sidebarmenu` as below.
In the implementation, the `renderUI` for "b" output is only executed when the menu is "b".

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(id = "sidebarmenu",
                menuItem("A", tabName = "a",  icon = icon("group", lib="font-awesome")),
                menuItem("B", tabName = "b", icon = icon("check-circle", lib = "font-awesome")),
                conditionalPanel("input.sidebarmenu == 'a'",
                                 uiOutput('A_panel')
                ),
                conditionalPanel("input.sidebarmenu == 'b'",
                                 uiOutput('B_panel')
                )
    ),
    sliderInput("x", "Outside of menu", 1, 100, 50)
  ),
  dashboardBody()
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$A_panel <- renderUI({
    if(input$sidebarmenu != "a") return()
    cat('Inside A Panel \n')
    sliderInput("b", "Under A", 1, 100, 50)
  })
  output$B_panel <- renderUI({
    if(input$sidebarmenu != "b") return()
    cat('Inside B Panel \n')
    sliderInput("b", "Under B", 1, 100, 50)
  })

}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

However, in this implementation the computation is conducted every time you switch the menu, since the change in `sidebarmenu` triggers the `renderUI`.
This may not be exactly what you want since you are concerned with the demanding computation when loading the menu "b".  You may want that computation happens only after the "b" menu is selected, but never again.

To do so, you can let the app to remember if the outputB has been rendered or not using `reactiveValues`, and terminate `renderUI` if it has been already rendered.
In the implementation below you will see the message printed only once.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(id = "sidebarmenu",
                menuItem("A", tabName = "a",  icon = icon("group", lib="font-awesome")),
                menuItem("B", tabName = "b", icon = icon("check-circle", lib = "font-awesome")),
                conditionalPanel("input.sidebarmenu == 'a'",
                                 uiOutput('A_panel')
                ),
                conditionalPanel("input.sidebarmenu == 'b'",
                                 uiOutput('B_panel')
                )
    ),
    sliderInput("x", "Outside of menu", 1, 100, 50)
  ),
  dashboardBody()
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  RV <- reactiveValues(b_ui_flg=FALSE)

  output$A_panel <- renderUI({
    if(input$sidebarmenu != "a") return()
    cat('Inside A Panel \n')
    sliderInput("b", "Under A", 1, 100, 50)
  })

  observeEvent(input$sidebarmenu, {
    if(input$sidebarmenu != "b") return()
    if (RV$b_ui_flg) return() 
    RV$b_ui_flg <- TRUE
    cat('Inside B Panel \n')
    output$B_panel <- renderUI({
      sliderInput("b", "Under B", 1, 100, 50)
    })
  })

}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Excellent answer. I did try a variant of ` if(input$sidebarmenu != "a") return()`. That did not work for me. But I was on a very old shiny version. I will blame that for now. +1 for the second approach.

Comment: I'm going through a similar situation but I don't get the meaning of the return() after the if conditions. Can you please clarify it? I think it's not very common to use it in that way

Comment: `return` would skip the rest of the computation if the condition is met.  That's called "early return" or "early exit" approach in general.

Comment: You might wonder why we can return a value if it is not a function.  In that case, note that a reactive expression in shiny can return a value.  We could also write the same operation without using a lot of returns, but early-return helps the code with less nests, and I thought this way the logic was clearer to people.